# how to include two id from different table into one column in postgres using nest

Tags: postgresql, nestjs

Realtions database:

[image]

i want to pick vendor id and purchase id into one column at column document id

**what should i do to combine these two fields into the document_id column, because i trying use join column it will create two different columns in the approval table**

example code

```
@ManyToOne(() => Vendor, (vendor) => vendor.id)
@JoinColumn({ name: 'document_id' })
document_id: Vendor;

@ManyToOne(() => Purchase, (purchase) => purchase.id)
@JoinColumn({ name: 'document_id' })
document_id: Purchase;
```

i use nestjs and postgre, and use typeorm to connect them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ManyToMany(() => MenuEntity, (menuEntity) => menuEntity.roles)
  @JoinTable({
    name: "rcon_role_menu",
    joinColumn: {
      name: "role_id",
      referencedColumnName: "id",
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: "menu_id",
      referencedColumnName: "id",
    },
  })
  menus: MenuEntity[];
```

**This may be helpful to you**